# Javascript form validation: form is submited on false return:

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, dom-events

When I'm trying to validate the form using Javascript it brings the alerts up as it should but the form gets submitted as nothing happened even though false is returned, the alert work only for the first time I press the submit button. Could some one tell me what am I doing wrong:

**Javascript:**

```
 function checkForm() {

       var name, email, text;

        name =  document.contact.userName.value;
        email = document.contact.email.value;
        text =  document.contact.textarea.value;

        //document.write(name + " " + email + " " + text);

        if (name == "" || email =="" || text=="")    {

             alert("Please fill all fields before submitting!");
             return false;

        }else if (!looksLikeMail(email))     {

         alert("Please enter you real email!");
             return false;
        }else       {

             alert("Your feedback was sent, Thank you!");
             return true;
            }    
 }

function looksLikeMail(str)     {

              var lastAtPos = str.lastIndexOf('@');
              var lastDotPos = str.lastIndexOf('.');
              return ((lastAtPos < lastDotPos) && lastAtPos > 0 && str.indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (str.length - lastDotPos) > 2);
>        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="contact" action="login" method="POST" onsubmit="checkForm()">
                <input type="hidden" name="page" value="feedback">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="textinput1">
                            Name:
                        </label>
                        <input id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" value="" type="text" name="userName"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="textinput2">
                            Email
                        </label>
                        <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" value="" type="email" name="email" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textarea1">
                            Feedback
                        </label>
                        <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter your text here" name="textarea"></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`<form name="contact" action="login" method="POST" onsubmit="checkForm()">`

to

`<form name="contact" action="login" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()">`

The `onsubmit` will cancel the submission if your function returns false, but only if `onsubmit` will also return false. So you have to pass the return value from `checkForm()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this suggestion didnt helped me.

Comment: Do you get any errors? My point is that the above code works unless there is something else going on.

Comment: @EmilAdj: Within `checkForm` function, wrap the code with `try...catch` block and return `false` on exception.

Comment: i get the: Cannot return from outside a function or method, when i put the return before the function in the onsubmit event. other then that Eclipse doesn't show me anything.

Comment: Hi, Jay. tried the "Try and catch statment", not working either.

Comment: I've just tried your code with my modification, and it works as expected. I did notice that you have `<` at the end of your JS code, remove that. And report if you get any errors! That is always the first step you take when debugging.

Comment: Look, help me help you. Check the god damned JS console for any errors.

Comment: the < sign left from the code section modeification on this site, it's not present i my code, Thank you Jan for your assistance, did you noticed a problem with the code that presents the alert only for the first submit?